# Forcing a splash page to load for every visitor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developing a landing page for a musician's upcoming release. I'd like to have this [splash page](http://www.natnalex.com/april22) load every time a visitor visits the [home page](http://www.natnalex.com/), but I don't want to make the splash page the base href. Is js the best way to do this? Any pointers? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the splash page to load WITHIN the home page, or instead of?

Comment: Instead, not within. In the footer of splash page is a link home that says "CONTINUE HOME."

Comment: Ah, if you hadn't told me I wouldn't have found it! If you want to do it (I don't recommend it) then you should probably just swap the files around and make the "Splash page" the default document.

Comment: Replacing one for the other definitely isn't ideal. Another alternative is to use a js redirect function from home to splash, but that's not the best solution, either. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could see it working is like this pseudo code:

```
//On Home Page
if (SomeCookie == false/empty) {
   SomeCookie = true/notempty;
   window.location = SplashPage;
}
```

This way at least you could make sure it only directed to the splash page on the first visit. I would make the link to the home page bigger and more obvious on the splash page though

Answer (score 0):

theres a simple example for you:

i took the video from your `splash page` link, put it in the background and added a small splash message that shows using jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/hGH9s/

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear, but I'm not using that video anymore. It's hidden via CSS. Also not looking for a splash overlay on top of the main site. But, thanks for taking a look.

Comment: well the video i put there just so the example's background wont be boring, it doesnt have to be there... and regarding your question, you can store a cookie on client's pc with boolean value for "Visited" and make the landing page - your splash page and it will set visited to True on visit. so every time the splash loads, u check the cookie. if client already saw splash page, then redirect him to home

Comment: or, rather make the href page "default.html" and there make the check for Visited cookie and redirect to splash/home as needed